# How to avoid 'while(true)' with 'break' and rather use a 'for' loop?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have an application with a config file from which various settings are read. One of the settings is the cycles that the application is running.
If this variable `nLoops` is `-1` then it's supposed to run an infinite number of times. Otherwise it shall run `x` times.
At the moment this is how I implemented it. However I was wondering if there's a more straight forward way without the `while(true)` expression (I get a warning here):

```
//get nLoops from config file

int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    if (nLoops > -1 && i >= nLoops)
        break;
    i++;

   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Simply put your condition in the while, instead of in a if inside the while

Comment: In theory, you shouldn't continually increment `i` if the loop is to run infinitely because when you overflow `i` you invoke undefined behaviour.  In practice, you probably get away with it, but be aware of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `if` condition (inverted, since you're testing to stay in instead of break out) in the `while` condition:

```
while (nLoops == -1 || i < nLoops)
```

Or as a `for`:

```
for (i=0; (nLoops == -1) || (i < nLoops); i++)
```

Comment: Your for loop would execute the `stuff` part of the loop with a different value for `i`, something like: `for (i=0; (nLoops == -1) || (i++ < nLoops); )` would do.

Comment: The inversion of OP's `nLoops > -1 && ...` is `nLoops <= -1 || ...`  (assuming integer `nLoops`).  Unclear why this answer uses `nLoops == -1`.

Comment: @chux From the question: *if this variable `nLoops` is -1 then it's supposed to run infinite times*.  The original condition was faulty based on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `while(true)` with `for(;;)` to avoid warnings. The `for` loop with a missing controlling expression is explicitly defined in the standard, e.g., ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.8.5.3/2.

Answer (score 0):

This requires one more (boolean) variable, but avoid using break statement in your loop.

```
    // Here reads from configuration file

    bool isInfiniteLoop = false;
    i = 0;

    if(nLoops == -1)
    {
       isInfiniteLoop = true;
       nLoops = 1;
    }

    while(i < nLoops)
    {
         // here goes your code

         if(!isInfiniteLoop)
         {
            // If NOT infinite loop: increment counter, otherwise while condition will always be 0 < 1
            i++;
         }
    }
```